# How to create a BCRSAPrivateCrtKey object using CRT parameters?

Tags: java, rsa, bouncycastle

For my CA there is a database running in the background storing RSA keys by their CRT parameters.
Now a `BCRSAPrivateCrtKey` object shall be created by using the stored information in the database.

Hopefully you can help.

So is there any way to create a key object by using:

```
RSAPrivateCrtKeyParameters param = new RSAPrivateCrtKeyParameters(modulus,
        publicExponent, privateExponent, p, q, dP, dQ, qInv);
```

Comment: Stupid question maybe, but why do you require the internal Bouncy implementation class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec prvkeySpec = new RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec(
        modulus, publicExponent, privateExponent, primeP,
        primeQ, primeExponentP, primeExponentQ,
        crtCoefficient);
Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce
        .provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
KeyFactory kfact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
BCRSAPrivateCrtKey prk = (BCRSAPrivateCrtKey) kfact
       .generatePrivate(prvkeySpec);
```